# QTcpSocket to QTcpSocket in same object

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket

I am attempting to fake a transfer between two QTcpSockets that happen to be in the same class (which is a googletest fixture). The focus of this is to see if I can send multiple messages between the two and properly extract them again. However, it seems that the two sockets won't connect. Most of the posts I've seen that relate to this don't come up with a working answer, and being as this is definitely not the intended means of use, I'm not sure that there is a simple one.

What I have for setting up the connection:

```
class TTest : public ::testing::Test, public QObject
{
    //Q_OBJECT
protected:
    QTcpServer qserv;
    QTcpSocket qtcpsock1; //send
    QTcpSocket *qtcpsock2; //rcv

    TTest() : qserv(this), qtcpsock1(this)
    {

        while (!qserv.isListening()) 
        {
            qserv.listen();
        }
        qtcpsock1.connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, qserv.serverPort());
        qtcpsock2 = qserv.nextPendingConnection();
        qtcpsock1.waitForConnected();
        if (!qtcpsock2) std::cout << "socket 2 not initialized\n";
        qserv.close();
    }
}
```

Signals/slots currently not in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with this is that the event polling loop of the application will not run, so no events will be handled and your function calls will simply not work without it.

In short, the `waitForConnected()` call will wait for an event that never happens.

The natural solution with Qt is of course to use signals and slots, and let the normal application event loop run.

---

On a slightly related note: If you want internal communication within the same process consider something other than (heavy and complex) TCP sockets. Simple message queues? Anonymous pipes? Plain strings or arrays?

Comment: I'm trying to mimic something that is client-server inside of the test, and parsing data into and out of the socket is the real point of it. The eventual destination is two separate processes, but I was hoping I could test the parsing inside of one.

Comment: +1 for mentioning signal/slots, something like this `connect(qserv, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(acceptConnection()));` then in the `acceptConnection() { qtcpsocket2 = qserv->nextPendingConnection()`

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me increase my understanding here. I eventually had to take a different route and remove the whole socketing thing entirely.